# Does Anakin really not want to be on council?

Tags: star-wars, revenge-of-the-sith

> Obi-Wan: The fact of the matter is you are too close to the
> Chancellor. The council doesn't like it when he interferes in Jedi
> affairs.
>
> Anakin: **I swear to you, I didn't ask to be put on the council.**
>
> Obi-Wan: But **it's what you wanted.**

Does Anakin really not want to be on council?

Comment: He wants to be a master.  He doesn't care about being on the council except as a means to that end.

Comment: Anakin might have wanted to be on the council, but not asked for it.

Comment: In context, Anakin is saying that he didn't ask Palpatine to apply political pressure on his behalf. That doesn't mean he would be opposed to joining the Council on his own merits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The film's [official novelisation](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Episode_III_Revenge_of_the_Sith_(novelization)) goes into more detail about Anakin's desires. In short, the loss of his mother and his illicit relationship with with Padmé has driven him close to madness. His prophetic dreams of her death have left him with a borderline pathological ambition to save her, regardless of the cost. He's of the opinion that having access to the secret holocrons of the Jedi will give him the ability to do this.

> Palpatine had somehow seen into his secret heart, and had chosen to offer him the one thing he most desired in all the galaxy. **He didn’t care about the Council, not really-that was a childish dream. He didn’t need the Council. He didn’t need recognition, and he didn’t need respect. What he needed was the rank itself.**
>
> All that mattered was Mastery.
>
> All that mattered was Padme.
>
> This was a gift beyond gifts: **as a Master, he could access those forbidden holocrons in the restricted vault.**
>
> He could find a way to save her from his dream …
>
> He shook himself back to the present. “I … am overwhelmed, sir. But the Council elects its own members. They will never accept this.”

For the record, he's not lying to Obi-Wan. He didn't *ask* for a seat on the council, here merely voiced his frustration to Palpatine that he wasn't on the council despite being so puissant.